# Filter Results using checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to filter my results by using checkboxes. It displays the results which have checked items in common:

```
$('input').change(function() {

    var room_array = new Array(),
        loc_array = new Array();
    $('.br').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            room_array.push($(this).data('bedrooms'));
        }
    });
    $('.loc').each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            loc_array.push($(this).data('location'));
        }
    });
    //console.log(loc_array, room_array);
    $('li').each(function() {
        if ($.inArray($(this).data('location'), loc_array) > -1 && $.inArray($(this).data('bedrooms'), room_array) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```
<input data-bedrooms="1" class="br" type="checkbox">1 bedroom<br>
<input data-bedrooms="2" class="br" type="checkbox">2 bedrooms<br>
<input data-bedrooms="3" class="br" type="checkbox">3 bedrooms<br><br>

<input data-location="london" class="loc" type="checkbox">london<br>
<input data-location="new-york" class="loc" type="checkbox">new york<br>
<input data-location="paris" class="loc" type="checkbox">paris<br><br>    

<ul>
    <li data-bedrooms="1"  data-location="paris">1 bedroom apartment paris</li>
    <li data-bedrooms="1" data-location="paris">1 bedroom apartment</li>
        <! -- similar combinations -->
    <li data-bedrooms="2" data-location="new-york">2 bedroom apartment new yor</li>
</ul>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YEtgM/13/)**

The problem is that when only 1 type of checkbox is selected, the results for that checkbox don't display.

However, I want to allow the selection of only one type, e.g. either the number of bedrooms or the location. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Id suggest you change your code so that the data about the results are stored as JavaScript and then translate that to HTML with simple function, this would allow you to filter the results easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
if ($.inArray($(this).data('location'), loc_array) > -1 && $.inArray($(this).data('bedrooms'), room_array) > -1) {
```

With

```
if (($.inArray($(this).data('location'), loc_array) > -1 || !$('.loc:checked').length) && ($.inArray($(this).data('bedrooms'), room_array) > -1 || !$('.br:checked').length)) {
```

To accept any value for a group when that group has no checked checkboxes.

By the way, your fiddle had two entries for

```
<li data-bedrooms="2" data-location="paris">2 bedroom apartment paris</li>
```

I changed one of them to `london` as your first example suggested.

## [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/YEtgM/17/)

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
if ($.inArray($(this).data('location'), loc_array) > -1 && $.inArray($(this).data('bedrooms'), room_array) > -1)
```

should be

```
if ($.inArray($(this).data('location'), loc_array) > -1 || $.inArray($(this).data('bedrooms'), room_array) > -1)
```

Comment: how so? can you give the example that proves this?

Comment: Check "1 bedroom" and "paris". It should result only in two entries with "1 bedroom apartment paris", but it also shows London and some "2 bedroom apartments" in Paris.